# HTML Section Links Navigating to Wrong Location

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to Stack Overflow so please forgive me if this is a repeat question. I searched thoroughly, but could not figure this out.

I am building a zipline portfolio page using mostly Bootstrap v3.3.6 and cannot get my section links to navigate properly.

Here is a sample of my markup including the nav:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Matthew Shelbourn</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#bio">Bio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Body Section1 -->

<div>
<a name="bio"></a>
</div>

<div class="container" style="background-color:cadetblue;">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <span><img id="profile-image" class="img-responsive pull-left" style="margin-top: 4.1%; margin-bottom:4.1%;" src="#"></span>
    </div>
```

When I click on the link in my nav for "Bio" (or any of the other sections) it doesn't navigate to the top of the corresponding section. Instead, it navigates to an area about 1/3 of the way down from the top of the section.

This same issue happens with every section link I have. I'm sure it's something trivial, but what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: your `<a name...>` should be `<a id.. >`

Comment: add `id="bio"` inside your anchor tag.

Comment: @cyval Tried that and for some reason it still won't work. I've never had this issue before, but this is pretty much the first time I've worked with Bootstrap.